# Partial string matching question

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, one contains a list of newspapers and a sector postcode (so a partial post code) for that news paper. So for example 'BB5 2' 'Accrington Observer'. In another table i have a large list of full postcodes for example BB5 2HQ.

I want to produce a result set that contains the full postcode from the second table and the matching publication from the first table based on matching the partial code with the full code.

I tried this but it produces odd results, like blank publication with a postcode but always directly after a matching result;

```
SELECT sd.domain, p.postcodes FROM postcodes p left join sector_domains sd on p.postcodes LIKE CONCAT(sd.postcode,'%') ;
```

Comment: Quit tagging titles please. Questions already have a tagging mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The `left join` will ensure that all the rows in `postcodes` will be represented whether or not they have a matching row in `sector_domains`. If they don't have a matching row in `sector _domains`, the `sector_domains` fields will be `null`.

Would this explain the behaviour you are seeing? If so you could try something like:

```
SELECT sd.domain, p.postcodes FROM postcodes p join sector_domains sd where p.postcodes LIKE CONCAT(sd.postcode,'%') ;
```